# Why am I getting an empty screen in Eclipse when emulating a simple Hello World program for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I'm following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator

In it there is a simple code for a layout with a Text parser and a button. When I input the code in my Eclipse and "Run" the program I arrive at an empty Android phone simulation. The phone diplays "Android" across the screen and my program does not run. Please instruct me on where I am making a mistake. My code is equal to the code in the tutorial, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's booting. You just have to wait for the emulator to start. It's just like real Android devices: it takes a while to boot. When it shows the desktop, it will launch your application.

On slow machines it might take a **while** (and I mean a good while). May I suggest a faster/stronger machine, or even better, a real Android device, for testing.

For better performance, do not close emulator window, this way it won't have to boot each time.

Comment: I see. My machine is a single core with 2GB RAM, but considering that SINGLE core, I think that's exactly my problem. I'll give it a go again and wait around 30 minutes. If it doesn't resolve, I'll repost here. Thank you kindly for pro help, as always :)

Comment: 30 minutes? damn.. my dual core 2.7GHz 4GB RAM takes about 2/3 minutes. and it's already a lot.

Comment: You were right, it did boot eventually, but it's running horribly, very laggy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as answered if you consider the answer is useful. Welcome to SO ;)